# How to display text file on async Webserver using esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++, esp8266wifi

I have several txt files on my SD card that I would like to output to my async webserver. I use the ESP8266 for this.
I have tried it with the following call. However, an error is then displayed.
It also says that two SD.h libraries were found:

```
Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.2/libraries/SD

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries/SD
```

the latter is not used.

The error I get is the following:

```
no matching function for call to 'AsyncWebServerRequest::send(SDClass&, const char [12], const char [10])'
```

how can I solve this problem?

```
server.on("/getdata", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
request->send(SD, "/subj1_1.txt", "text/plain");
});
```

Comment: update the Arduino IDE

Comment: i am on the latest version

Comment: The SD.h from the esp8266 folder is used. So I should try to use the one for the Arduino ?

Comment: sorry no. It looks like you have to use SDFS library with AsyncWebServerRequest. it is bundled with the esp8266 Arduino core

Comment: so I included the SDFS.h library and changed the request to: 
request->send(SDFS, "/subj1_1.txt", "text/plain");
the error is gone but when I open the /getdata link I got a empty page